# Get IP address from request in Http-Server

Tags: node.js, http, npm

I have the code to get the IP address and load balance as follows:

```
var httpProxy = require("http-proxy");
var http = require('http');
var where=require('node-where');    
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
var server=http.createServer( function (req, res){
    console.log(req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress);

    var country,state
    where.is(req.connection.remoteAddress, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        country=result.get('countryCode');
        // state=result.get('regionCode');
        if(country!='US')
        {
            proxy.web(req, res, {target: "http://localhost:3000"}, function (e){
                proxy.web(req, res, {target: "http://localhost:3001"});
            });
        }
        else
        {
            proxy.web(req, res, {target: "localhost:3001"}, function (e){
                proxy.web(req, res, {target: "localhost:3000"});
            });
        }
    });
});

server.listen(80);
```

however, the console log returns just `::1`. The IP address is not visible in the request.

How do I get the IP address of the machine accessing the website in order for me to load balance based on the country of the IP address?

Comment: Is this node server behind a reverse proxy like NGINX or similar?  Also, is this actually running on a network from you, or are you doing everything on localhost?